# Connecting to local hosted applications from google app engine (for java)?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was wondering if its possible to to connect (thro' SSO) to a locally (in my env) hosted application from a java web application running on google app engine. Assume I have an application based on a tool/framework which cannot be moved on to the app engine due to the app engines various restrictions. Is it feasible keep this application in house while building any extensions I need onto a application running on the app engine? So I enter thro' the main application on the app engine, do a SSO to my local app for any features I need from this app, but use the rest of the features from the main application on the engine itself.

I see that there are solns where force.com integrates with google app engine (exposing webservices). Likewise I thought it might be possible to connect to local apps at a screen level using SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use [Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/) to access your internal services from an App Engine app.